# Error during log out in Dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

when i log out from my website that is made in dnn, A error message Shows:- a critical error occurred.
I check all the skins files and every thing but cannot find any error/solution to remove this error.
How this error be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Please go: Admin-->Event Viewer to see the details message of the error. Maybe you can find the root cause. If not, please add a more detailed description for question, then others can help you.